# grabbing members from structs

Tags: ruby, struct

I want to be able to iterate through some xml i'm using structs and I want to be able to grab the members from them after adding them to an array, is the way i'm doing it wrong?

I want lots of different structs to be saved to the same array and call them by

```
systems.os 
systems.base
systems.network
```

at the moment I have

```
System = Struct.new(:os, :base, :number)
Networks = Struct.new(:network)

  systems = []

  filename = "/lib/xml/boxes.xml"
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(filename))

    doc.search('//systems/system').map do |system|

    systems << System.new(
      system.at('@os').text, 
      system.at('@basebox').text, 
      system.at('@number').text)

    systems << Networks.new(
      system.css('networks network').collect do |network| 
        { 'network' => network['name'] } 
    end)
  end
```

at the moment if i do

```
puts systems
```

it returns

```
#<struct System os="linux", base="precise32", number="1">
#<struct Networks network=[{"network"=>"homeonly"}, {"network"=>"homeonly2"}]>
```

but i can't do

```
puts systems.os
Error: undefined method `os' for #<Array:0x007fa6198b2e20>
```

Updated XML to suggest why I would want them in the same array..

```
<systems>
<systems>
<system number="1" os="linux" basebox="precise32" >
<network name="homeonly" ></network>
<network name="homeonly2"></network>
</networks>
</system>


<system number="2" os="linux" basebox="AddBaseBox" >
<networks>
<network name="homeonly" ></network>
<network name="homeonly2"></network>
</networks>
</system>
</systems>
```

there are other attributes i'm accessing and adding to the array also shorted for this example. the reason why I want to talk to each object individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I as looking for, using a class instead of struct.

```
class System
  attr_accessor :os, :base, :number, :network
end

def read_systems_xml
  systems = []

  filename = "/lib/xml/boxes.xml"
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(filename))

    doc.search('//systems/system').map do |system|

      system_class = System.new
      system_class.os = system.at('@os').text
      system_class.base = system.at('@basebox').text
      system_class.number = system.at('@number').text

    system_class.network = system.css('networks network').collect do |network| 
      { 'network' => network['name'] } 
    end
    systems << system_class
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
puts systems[0].os
```

or:

```
p systems.map { |s| s.os }
```

Actually the `map` call I suggested above will only work if you are more disciplined about what you put in the `systems` array.  You should probably not put Network objects in the systems array, the way you are doing now.

It is important to remember that `systems` should be an array of `System` objects, but it is not a `System` object itself so it doesn't know what `os` means.  You need to use array methods to get the elements of the array.

Comment: p systems.map { |s| s.os } would work if i didn't have other structs in there undefined method `os' for #<Networks:0x007fd7fa8a07a8>

Comment: Yeah, it seems to me that an array called `systems` should not contain networks.  But I don't really know what you are doing.  If you have a reason to put both types of things in one array, I would at least rename the array.

Comment: yeah it's not the best term i guess.. If I were create two separate arrays how would I return them both from a method to access? I only threw them into one so they were both accessible.. i will display my xml it might explain the situation further

Comment: How about returning them in a hash?  `{ :systems => systems, :networks => networks}`  Or you could make your own class to represent the result set.

Comment: OK now that I see that each network belongs to a system, my previous comment would not be good.

Comment: You should figure out how to store the networks as a member of the System struct.  Each System object would have an array of Networks inside.